# Access web part properties from within CMSRepeater Template

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Is there any way I can access a webpart's properties from withing a repeater's template (or vice versa)?

```
<div ID="RepeaterWrapper" runat="server">
    <cms:CMSRepeater ID="repItems" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- I want to access this div in my code behind or else have it access a property from the code behind-->
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </cms:CMSRepeater>
</div>
```

I want to set the inner div's bg color and I can't use classes as the property is given as a hexadecimal color so it would mean a few thousand classes!

Worst case scenario I can do it with some js but would rather a "purer" way of doing it if it exists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your datasource has that background color in the returned data, once you bind your datasource to the repeater you have access to that within the item templates.  Simply use something like this:

`<div class="col-sm-4 <%# Eval("BgColorColumnName") %>">`

Now if you want to set a value from the actual webpart itself, you need to make sure the property is a public property then you can use something like:

`<div class="col-sm-4 <%# YourPublicPropertyName %>">`

Comment: Just for clarity, it was wanting the property from the webpart itself. I had always been using ´control.Attributes['css'] += value´ in the code behind up until now

Comment: @rory that is the recommended approach.  I'd shy away from setting things in the ascx layout file like this mainly because an end user can edit the ascx layout file in the Kentico UI.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the items going to have the same color? If its per item, then modify the items you are pulling to include the value.

Answer (score 0):

If this was in portal method you could grab the XML from the Page Template table and get values from it.  Since it's purely from code, and it's a repeater, usually you need to store the data somewhere outside the repeater itself (in the items you repeat, or in the current page form data).

If you can access it anywhere from a Macro, then you can use the CMS.MacroEngine.MacroContext.Current.ResolveMacro() to resolve that and get the value.

Can you give us a little more info on where the div BG color would be stored? why it has to be in the repeater itself?